# Как выглядит запрос по нахождению менеджера, у которого наибольшее число служащих?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sql-server

1. У меня есть таблица employee
2. В этой таблице есть поля:
   а) Manager_ID - это номер служащего, кому подчинен
   б) Last_name/First_name - фамилия/имя менеджера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как выглядит запрос? Ну, как запрос))) Точнее вопросы задавайте и прикладывайте Ваши попытки разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: Обычно выглядит. Группируешь по манагеру. Сортируешь по количеству записей по убыванию, берёшь только первую. К результату прикручиваешь ещё одну копию таблицы и получаешь фамилие. Всё. Это при условии, что в случае наличия нескольких манагеров с одинаковым и максимальным количеством - нужен только один, причём пофиг кто.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.